# Pass Date '1900-01-01' from angular to wcf

Tags: javascript, json, angular, date, wcf

When I call with following json

```
{

      "EndDate": "\/Date(" + date + ")\/"
}
```

It changes to 1970 year

When I call without Date, it throws serialization issue.

I am using angular 7 and WCF.

How could I pass '1900-01-01 00:00:00' to wcf from angular

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JSON` does not support `Date` objects so you need to use a `timestamp` (int) or a `DateString`(string) and finally parse it in `WCF`

```
{

  "EndDate":  date.getTime() // Timestamp in ms 
 }
```